# Can I migrate a PHP site to WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, migration, migrate

I would like to migrage a PHP site to WordPress so I can update the information written on the website.

Does anyone know the best way I can do this? I did ask a few people regarding this and the general consesus was to completely redo the website.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. And yes, those other people you spoke to are correct, its essentially a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to redo large parts of your webpage. If you have an existing design you will need to learn how to create a theme in wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development or you can use on of the many already available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use wordpress theme development for migration php into the wordpress...